Error when applying function to a column in data frame
I had a label column from a pandas dataframe that had so many variance. I want to narrow it down by putting some of the label to another label I chose.
The data is supposed to be like this (both column are in dtype string):



old_label
new_label




health
health


healthy_tips
health


rejuvenation
health


government
government


senate
government


governor
government



So I apply this function that inspect every substring element of the inputs:
def relabel(x):
    for i in x:
        if ("health" or "rejuvenation") in i:
            return "health"
        elif ("gover" or "senate") in i:
            return "government"
        else:
            return i

Then I apply using:
data['new_label'] = data['old_label'].apply(relabel)

But it immediately return the exact same value by its input, so the result is just a new column with the exact same data.
How to fix this?

Two mistakes: the function will get passed one value, so you don't have to for over it, and the syntax for checking substrings is wrong:
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "old_label": [
            "health",
            "healthy_tips",
            "rejuvenation",
            "government",
            "senate",
            "governor",
        ]
    }
)


def relabel(x):
    if "health" in x or "rejuvenation" in x:
        return "health"
    elif "gover" in x or "senate" in x:
        return "government"
    else:
        return x


data["new_label"] = data["old_label"].apply(relabel)

print(data)

Output:
      old_label   new_label
0        health      health
1  healthy_tips      health
2  rejuvenation      health
3    government  government
4        senate  government
5      governor  government


I see, thank you. But the problem is, the multiple substring keyword I want to check are far more varied than the example I gave here, is there no other way than to type the condition 1 by 1? Like collecting the substring in a list first, then check based on list?

You can do if any(y in x for y in ["health", "rejuvenation"]):.

If there are a lot of substrings to check in one condition, using a regex may be faster: if re.match('health|rejuvenation', x):.

An alternative using a dict:
labels = {"health": ["health", "rejuvenation"], "government": ["gover", "senate"]}


def relabel(x):
    for new_label, old_values in labels.items():
        if any(old_value in x for old_value in old_values):
            return new_label
    return x


data["new_label"] = data["old_label"].apply(relabel)

      old_label   new_label
0        health      health
1  healthy_tips      health
2  rejuvenation      health
3    government  government
4        senate  government
5      governor  government


The issue with your function is the way the conditions are evaluated within the if and elif statements. The condition "health" (or "rejuvenation") in i does not work because "health" (or "rejuvenation") evaluates to "health" (the first truthy value), and then it checks if "health" is in i.
You can correct the function
import pandas as pd

data = pd.DataFrame({
    'old_label': ['health', 'healthy_tips', 'rejuvenation', 'government', 'senate', 'governor']
})
def relabel(x):
    if "health" in x or "rejuvenation" in x:
        return "health"
    elif "gover" in x or "senate" in x:
        return "government"
    else:
        return x

data['new_label'] = data['old_label'].apply(relabel)

print(data)

which gives
      old_label   new_label
0        health      health
1  healthy_tips      health
2  rejuvenation      health
3    government  government
4        senate  government
5      governor  government


I see, thank you. But the problem is, the multiple substring keyword I want to check are far more varied than the example I gave here, is there no other way than to type the condition 1 by 1? Like collecting the substring in a list first, then check based on list?

What you can do is use if any() statements
